# Converting Inner Join Grouping SQL into Linq

Tags: sql, linq

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT b.Brand_key, b.BrandName, Sum(po.Quantity) AS Quantity 
FROM Brands b
INNER JOIN Products p ON b.Brand_key = p.Brand_fkey
INNER JOIN ProductOrders po ON p.Product_key = po.Product_fkey
GROUP BY b.Brand_key
ORDER BY Quantity DESC, b.BrandName ASC
```

which works perfectly. Distinct values are returned as expected. I've attempted to turn it into Linq, but I feel like I'm going down a rabbit hole that never ends.

```
var testModelTwo = 
        (from b in db.Brands
         join p in db.Products on b.brandKey equals p.brandKey
         select new { brandKey = b.brandKey, BrandName = b.BrandName, ProductKey = p.productKey }
         into groupResultBP
         join po in pom on groupResultBP.ProductKey equals po.Product_fkey
         select new
            {
                brandKey = groupResultBP.brandKey,
                BrandName = groupResultBP.BrandName,
                Quantity = po.Quantity
            } into gr
         group gr by gr.brandKey into gd
         select new { Brand = gd.Key, BrandCounter = gd.Sum(c => c.Quantity) } into sumGroup
         select sumGroup).ToList();
```

This seems to get to the point where I have a key and the sum, but need to do another join to get back the brand item information with sumGroup.

I feel like I've gone round the houses about 100 times and this is much easier than I'm making it! Is what I've done so far correct?

Comment: Would it not be better to post the related classes and some words what you want to achieve?

Comment: @core All I'm really asking is for the Linq that give the same output as the SQL statement. The last 80% of the post is probably just proof that I've given it a go and not just trying to get SO to do my work for me. :-). I felt like posting any other code would be unneeded as the SQL statement gives the structure of the database and the output.Do you feel like it needs more?

Comment: Yes. Because to create the own statement (independent from any data), I would need to create the classes first. So from my point of view it would be good to have the corresponding classes with the properties you want to query...